# How do I get Google-Maps API working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

I have an existing project I'm trying to get Google Maps working in. I followed Google Map's documentation, but here's how it went:

Created `Podfile` in my project directory. It contains:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Then I run `pod install`. It gives me two warnings:

```
    [!] The `My App [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
        - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
        - Remove the build settings from the target.

    [!] The `My App [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
        - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
        - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I tried using the `$(inherited)` flag, it didn't do anything. I removed the build settings, and it gave me ~90 errors. I'm using a few other frameworks (Parse, Facebook SDK) so I don't think changing those flags are an option.

Then I open the project using `myApp.xcworkspace`.

In `appDelegate.m` I added `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` ([Google's tuorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) just says `#import <GoogleMaps.h>` but that's what Xcode auto filled for me, and it was saying `GoogleMaps.h` wasn't found). Then in my `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I've added `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"myAPIKey"];`.

When I try to run it gives me two errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Both the second and last lines are the ones highlighted. I've tried what I could find from searching those errors - dragging the framework to the Link Binary with Libraries (gave me ~90 errors), and checking that I was importing a `.h` and not a `.m`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest trying 2 things:

1. Do again what you did with the `$(inherited)`. It's a must.
2. In both projects settings (your app and the pod), change `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No`.

Comment: Didn't work, still gives the same two errors. I just want to make sure I'm adding the flags correctly - like this http://i.imgur.com/FJcR2B8.png ?

Comment: Yes, but it should be for both release and debug

Comment: Right. I tried it, and only building for armv7 and armv7s. And using older versions of some of the frameworks (saw it on another quesiton). I also tried using a `-force_load` for the Google framework in place of `-ObjC` and that wasn't working either.

Comment: After doing what I suggested, did the warning disappeared (of the pod install) ?

Comment: Yeah. I discarded all my changes from before trying to get the maps API in,  added `$(inherited)` to both and when I did the `pod install` the two errors did not show up. However the architecture errors still happened.

Comment: And both your project and the pod project add `NO` for `Build Active Architecture Only`?

Comment: i only added this : $(inherited)